# Setting check box to lock after a certain event.

Tags: html, if-statement, checkbox, progress-bar, completion

So I am new to coding and am just trying to make a simple background project for something a friend and I thought up. I am using HTML for this just to start. 
I want to make a list of checkboxes with the fifty states and a progress bar. Now as you click each state's checkbox the bar fills up and then when you have clicked  all fifty then a check box at the top of the screen next to the progress bar is checked and there is a small saying under each saying Congratulations!

If anyone can help me I would be greatly appreciative!

Thank you, Kaxwell.

Answer (score 0):

It is unfortunately not possible to perform all this using only HTML. You can build form etc. with HTML. The logic has to be managed by some other language. I suggest JavaScript in this case. Have a look at [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/) to start with it.
Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Using bootstrap and JQuery, you could achieve it:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-10">
            <div class="progress">
                <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="45" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
            <input id="ccomplete" class="form-control" type="checkbox" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="main" class="row">
        <input class="form-control" type="checkbox" />
    </div>
</div>
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo with the complete code](https://jsfiddle.net/anoorally/c10n2fsn/1/)

I encourage you to learn javascript/jquery for such manipulations.

The above demo uses *JQuery* and *Bootstrap* frameworks.